# Import data with integers and lists in Python

Tags: python, import

I have a txt file with data sorted like that:

period, 0.6, diameter, 1.6, freqs, [1. 1.12 1.61 ...], ...

I need to import both the integers and the lists of numbers. I use:

```
period=[]
diameter = []
freqs =[]

with open('OptBEparams.txt', 'r') as f:


    lines = f.read()
    data = lines.strip().split(", ")

    for i in range(0, int(len(data)/12)):

        period.append(float(data[1+i*11]))
        diameter.append(float(data[3+i*11]))
        freqs.append(list(data[5+i*11]))
```

While I end up with nice lists period and diameter with my values, I have no idea how to import the lists in a good way. The above command obviously takes in every symbol separately.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is to get string like this: `[1. 1.12 1.61]` and pass it into this function:

```py
def get_list(st: str):
    nst = st[1:-1].split(' ')
    return map(float, nst)
```

and you will get map of floats. Or if you need only list you can just use this:

```py
def get_list(st: str):
    nst = st[1:-1].split(' ')
    return list(map(float, nst))
```